# Is there a way to download, from iPad mini, videos created in an app?

Tags: ipad, applications, data-transfer

I am trying to download 7+ gb of videos that my daughter has on her iPad mini. The videos were made in the app musical.ly and I would like to get them from the iPad to my Macbook. I cannot figure out a way to do this and would appreciate any ideas.

Comment: Assuming they were exported to a music format and not left as individual music snippets in the project, you should be able to simply connect the iPad to your computer's iTunes and browse the audio content that way. It will give you the option to synchronize the tracks to your computer. With a file size of 7GB, you probably don't want to upload everything to the cloud, hence a direct transfer would be much more efficient. I don't have first-hand experience with musical.ly specifically but I imagine the exporting procedures are pretty standard across the apps. Is that helpful in any way?

Comment: Thanks for the response. The issue seems to be that they are not in any kind of music file that I can see anywhere other than in the app itself. I can share them from her ipad to mine, via text, but one by one is just too tedious.

Comment: I'm pretty sure if you follow this guide you can do it: [About File Sharing on iPhone, iPad, and iPod touch - Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201301). I don't know about that app specifically, but this is the first place I would look.